# Vim74: E149 Sorry no help for help.txt

Tags: vim

I just downloaded and installed vim74 on to my linux box.  I'm only installing locally, for the user.  When I go into vim, and do :help, I get the error.

I tried adding:

```
let $VIM='home/myuser/vim74'
let $VIMRUNTIME='home/myuser/vim74/runtime'
```

to my .vimrc but it didn't help.  How can I fix this?

Comment: Well, well, well, let's start with *how* (what commands you used) you installed Vim in the first place would you?

Comment: I dled the vim tarball, extracted and ran make

Comment: See [the answer by njd to “Vim - errors E433 No tags file, E149 No help for help.txt” on Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/515699/vim-errors-e433-no-tags-file-e149-no-help-for-help-txt).

Answer (score 7):

When building vim yourself and installing locally it seems that you need to generate the helptags manually from within vim since the build process doesn't seem to do it.  I ran into this very same issue when building the latest vim version 8.0.311.  I followed the link in Ben Klein's comment above, but both my &helpfile and &runtimepath were correct, yet I still received the E149 error when doing :help which I assume is your situation as well postelrich.

I found the helptags solution here:

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/1087

Even though I was installing vim locally on a centos system and not a mac, the issue seems to be universal.  I just replaced $VIMRUNTIME with the path to the local vim runtime installed from make install, which in your case may be something like /home/myuser/vim74/runtime

Specifically I ran this from within vim:

```
:helptags ~/share/vim/vim80/doc
```

In your case you will probably run something like:

```
:helptags ~/vim74/runtime/doc
```

Once done, :help should immediately start working again without having to restart vim.

Comment: make sure you type `doc` and not `docs`.  Good night I must have done that 30 times before I figured out what was going on.

Comment: :helptags command is doing nothing in vim. It just takes cursor above. is something wrong with installation of vim? using centos 6.9

Answer (score 0):

You can get the same “*E149 Sorry no help for help.txt*” error if you have a long-running Vim session and the Vim program files were upgraded in the meantime.

This happened to me: I had started an editing session in a GNU screen window on my Debian `testing` system using Vim 8.1. Some time later, `unattenttended-upgrades` upgraded Vim 8.1 to 8.2 with the result that the run-time paths were now no longer valid. I could have saved the session and restarted Vim, but it was simpler/easier to run the following command (specific to 8.2):

```
:set helpfile=/usr/share/vim/vim82/doc/help.txt
```